# How to develop the backend while working with Flutter

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, dart, backend

I am pretty new to flutter.I just developed a reminder app.But that was mostly only front-end.But my next project I want to build a meat delivery service app.But this requires me to work on the backed as well.I have been getting pretty vague answers on the backend part of flutter.

Can anyone explain what like how exactly should I go with backend.I know Python for the start.Also you can use dart as well.I am confused.I just want to finish off things in the optiminum period of time.

Comment: Firebase would be a good start..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the App Write.io, this project is open-source and free, you can install the server and everything will free for you. Btw: App Write has the Flutter SDK. And this project has much big community

Can you more information from [here](https://appwrite.io/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @secret for the answer

Answer (score 0):

firebase is pretty good but you need to have an API. there is no other way to do backend without API. here is the whole documentation about **restApi** *https://medium.com/swlh/restful-api-documentation-made-easy-with-swagger-and-openapi-6df7f26dcad*

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See  [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)